# Multiple table joins with aggregate (mssql / sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate

Very simple question. What I want to do is select all columns from one table and sum of one column (which could have multiple matching rows) from another table.

Example:

```
table ta (eid, uid, name, year, etc, etc, etc)
table tb (eid, uid, name, year, amount, etc, etc)
```

`eid` - will not match between both table
`uid, name, year` - will match across both tables

So I want to pull out all columns from table `ta`, simple:

```
select * from ta where eid='value';
```

I want to join amount column from table `tb` to my resultset, simple:

```
select a.*, b.amount
from ta a
inner join tb b on a.year=b.year
where a.eid='value';
```

Great, this works fine. But what if I have multiple rows in table tb?

Executing:

```
select a.*, sum(b.amount)
from ta a inner join tb b on a.uid=b.uid
where a.year='value';
```

gives me the following error:

> Column 'ta.eid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So I add:

```
select a.*, sum(b.amount)
from ta a inner join tb b on a.uid=b.uid
where a.year='value' group by ta.uid;
```

And I get the same error!

However, if I change my query to:

```
select a.uid, a.year, sum(b.amount)
from ta a inner join tb b on a.uid=b.uid
where a.year='value'
group by ta.uid, ta.year;
```

It works, but now I have three columns instead of all columns that I wanted.

So, at this point my question becomes: Is there a better, cleaner way of structuring this query other than me manually typing out all columns I want to pull from two tables with GROUP BY clause?

Comment: For what it's worth [it is not good practice to use `SELECT *` in production code](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). It might save you 30 seconds when writing queries, but could cost you more in the long run.

Comment: The reason why I am using `Select *` from one table is because 97% of columns get populated into update form which subsequently will update a table records in the database.

Comment: Actually does my question even makes sense? Should I elaborate a bit more or provide a better table column structure or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can preaggregate in a subquery:

```
select a.*, b.sumb
from ta a left join
     (select b.uid, sum(b.amount) as sumb
      from tb b
      group by b.uid
     ) b
     on a.uid=b.uid
where a.year = 'value';
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but throws me an error that `Column 'b.uid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Would it have something to do with the fact that I do `sum(cast(b.amount as money)) as sumb` because amount is stores a `varchar` formated string?

Comment: Indeed that `group by b.uid` solved the error that was annoying me. Cheers lads.

Comment: I had to update my solution to use `left join` to account for times when there are no matching records in table b. (incase someone else reads this)